# POST or Get Request with Json response in C# windows Form App

Tags: c#, .net, json, post, get

I made an API in server side with PHP + Laravel framework which accept both GET & Post requests with some special parameters.

It's address is : http://beresun.ir/API/Orders/0

and it gets these parameters :

```
token > string ,
restaurant_id > integer ,
admin_id > integer ,
token_id > integer .
```

if we send a request with GET method with these parameters, for example it will be :

http://beresun.ir/API/Orders/0?token=2JEuksuv86DcFmLrQa7nna4QDeowuGTqpyUK0pf9wSlbe6D5hLtEVxvzMT5gAZG0xBKy00HxS3J79mcr8F54dBD0uIg5HX5fzPOAP&restaurant_id=1&admin_id=2&token_id=40 which returns a json data , you can click on the link to see the results .

the response json data includes some information about customers and it's products.

now I want to make a windows application for this service with C# and request data from this API with POST or GET methods :

I want to use this API to get Json data from Web server and save them in my Windows application , So I created two functions in one of my Form Classes :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MainActivity : Form
{
    string token = "2JEuksuv86DcFmLrQa7nna4QDeowuGTqpyUK0pf9wSlbe6D5hLtEVxvzMT5gAZG0xBKy00HxS3J79mcr8F54dBD0uIg5HX5fzPOAP";
    int restaurant_id = 1;
    int admin_id = 2;
    int token_id = 40;
private void SendWebrequest_Get_Method()
{
    try
    {

        String postData = "token=" + token +
                "&restaurant_id=" + restaurant_id +
                "&admin_id=" + admin_id +
                "&token_id=" + token_id;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://beresun.ir/API/Orders/0?" + postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

        String json_text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_text);
        if (stuff.error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("problem with getting data", "Error");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(json_text, "success");
        }

        sr.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong request ! " + ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}


private void SendWebrequest_POST_Method()
{
    try
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://beresun.ir/API/Orders/5");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "token=" + token +
            "&restaurant_id=" + restaurant_id +
            "&admin_id=" + admin_id +
            "&token_id=" + token_id;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        MessageBox.Show(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong request ! " + ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
}
```

Now Here is the problem , when I test the API it works fine , but when I request data from my application , it returns error and not working .

Can anyone explain me how I should request data from this API , to get data , I searched a lot , and I used many different methods , but none of them worked for me . maybe because this API returns very much Json data or maybe request timeout happen. I don't know , I couldn't find the problem . So I asked it Here.

I don't know what I should do .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oki so i run your code :

```
  private string TestURL = "http://beresun.ir/API/";
    string token = "2JEuksuv86DcFmLrQa7nna4QDeowuGTqpyUK0pf9wSlbe6D5hLtEVxvzMT5gAZG0xBKy00HxS3J79mcr8F54dBD0uIg5HX5fzPOAP";
    int restaurant_id = 1;
    int admin_id = 2;
    int token_id = 40;
    public async Task<string> test()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var Client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(TestURL);
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                string postData = "token=" + token +
                "&restaurant_id=" + restaurant_id +
                "&admin_id=" + admin_id +
                "&token_id=" + token_id;
                HttpResponseMessage responce = await Client.GetAsync("Orders/0?" + postData);
                if (responce.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var Json = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    //  !
                    return Json;
                }
                else
                {
                    // deal with error or here ...
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and its working am getting the json file ,, i think your mistake is in postData  is string Not String ! a simple type can amazing harm !

Comment: Thanks Bro , really thank you . :) you saved my life . 

If you have any questions with android programming or web development ( php , laravel stuff ) just send me email peyman.forceman @ gmail. com .

Thanks

Comment: Where is the authorization credentials for api? How the api will identify the user actually ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 private string URL = "Your Base domain URL";
 public async Task<YourModel> getRequest()
        {
            using (var Client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage responce = await Client.GetAsync("Your Method or the API you callig");
                if (responce.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var Json = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var Items= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(Json);

                // now use you have the date on Items !
                    return Items;
                }
                else
                {
                    // deal with error or here ...
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it returns null . 
In Here :  if (responce.IsSuccessStatusCode) {}else{ return null; }

Comment: Are you sure the token is in the url !? 
test your APis using Postman

Comment: I used Postman , with both GET and Post methods , it works fine. :)

here it is an example of GET method:

http://beresun.ir/API/Orders/0?token=2JEuksuv86DcFmLrQa7nna4QDeowuGTqpyUK0pf9wSlbe6D5hLtEVxvzMT5gAZG0xBKy00HxS3J79mcr8F54dBD0uIg5HX5fzPOAP&restaurant_id=1&admin_id=2&token_id=40